# Is radio stream live on SomaFM SF10-33 online radio station?

Tags: radio

I am listening to https://somafm.com/sf1033/.
They describe it as:

> Live fire/police scanner audio from San Francisco processed and mixed with ambient and experimental music. A surreal audio zeitgeist of the city.

I am wondering if the audio from the radio scanner is live or being pre-recorded then put in the tracks by the musicians?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I emailed them and the DJ replied that the talk stream is live and put on top of the music in real time.

I find it quite stunning to produce music like that.